# NOT NULL constraint failed: ial_profile.user_id

Tags: python, django, web, django-forms

I am new to Django and was trying to follow a tutorial. But i came across this problem and is not able to solve it myself. When i try to access 127.0.0.1:8000/profile/id(1,2,3...) then it is throwing 'IntegrityError'.
Can anyone please help me to overcome it?

Code example :

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Profile

# Create your views here.

def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, "base.html")

def profile_list(request):
    profiles = Profile.objects.exclude(user=request.user.id)
    return render(request, "ial/profile_list.html", {"profiles": profiles})

def profile(request, pk):
    if not hasattr(request.user, 'profile'):
        missing_profile = Profile(user=request.user.id)
        missing_profile.save()

    profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
    # edit 1
    if request.method == "POST":
        current_user_profile = request.user.profile 
        data = request.POST
        action = data.get("follow")
        if action == "follow":
            current_user_profile.follows.add(profile)
        elif action == "unfollow":
            current_user_profile.follows.remove(profile)
        current_user_profile.save()
    return render(request, 'ial/profile.html', {'profile': profile})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.db.models.signals import post_save

from django.dispatch import receiver

# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follows = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self",
        related_name = "followed_by",
        symmetrical=False,
        blank=True
        )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        user_profile = Profile(user=instance)
        user_profile.save()
        user_profile.follows.set([instance.profile.id])
        user_profile.save()
```

**profile.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="column">

    <div class="block">
    <h1 class="title is-1">
        {{profile.user.username|upper}}'s djail
    </h1>
    </div>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="buttons has-addons">
        {% if profile in user.profile.follows.all %}
            <button class="button is-success is-static">Follow</button>
            <button class="button is-danger" name="follow" value="unfollow">
            Unfollow
        </button>
        {% else %}
            <button class="button is-success"name="follow" value="follow">Follow</button>
            <button class="button is-danger is-static">Unfollow</button>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="column is-one-third">

    <div class="block">
        <a href="{% url 'ial:profile_list' %}">
            <button class="button is-dark is-outlined is-fullwidth">
                All Profiles
            </button>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        <h3 class="title is-4">
            {{profile.user.username}} follows:
        </h3>
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
            {% for following in profile.follows.all %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{% url 'ial:profile' following.id %}">
                        {{ following }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        <h3 class="title is-4">
            {{profile.user.username}} is followed by:
        </h3>
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
            {% for follower in profile.followed_by.all %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{% url 'ial:profile' follower.id %}">
                        {{ follower }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

**Terminal Output**

Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 26, 2022 - 09:16:18
Django version 4.1.3, using settings 'social.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /profile/1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 357, in execute
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: ial_profile.user_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> ```
>
> line 55, in inner
> response = get_response(request)
> File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 197, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
> File "/home/kali/djial/social/ial/views.py", line 17, in profile
> missing_profile.save()
> File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
> line 812, in save
> self.save_base(
> File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
> line 863, in save_base
> updated = self._save_table(
> File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
> line 1006, in _save_table
> results = self._do_insert(
> File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
> line 1047, in _do_insert
> return manager._insert(
> File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py",
> line 85, in manager_method
> return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
> line 1790, in _insert
> return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
> File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",
> line 1660, in execute_sql
> cursor.execute(sql, params)
> File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 103, in execute
> return super().execute(sql, params)
> File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 67, in execute
> return self._execute_with_wrappers(
> File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
> return executor(sql, params, many, context)
> File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 84, in _execute
> with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
> File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
> line 91, in **exit**
> raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
> File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 89, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
> File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py",
> line 357, in execute
> return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: ial_profile.user_id
> [26/Nov/2022 09:16:29] "GET /profile/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 140002

I do know that the problem possibly is with missing_profile.save() and i have to use .save(commit=False) but don't know how to do it...

Thanks in advance.

Was trying to access 127.0.0.1:8000/profile/id(1,2,3...) but resulted in IntegrityError.

Comment: The error means that your Profile instance doesn't have user_id filled. Also I think you should specify related_name="profile" to your User.profile one-to-one field

Comment: And in the profile list maybe you want to get user's profiles, not anything by them? Then you should user .filter() instead of .exclude()